# Celerycam error - This code isn't under transaction management

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

My setup includes django 1.5.1, celery 3.1.0 and redis as the backend

`$ python manage.py celerycam  -b 'redis://localhost:6379/0'`

Makes celerycam run but it keeps on barfing the following:

```
TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management
[2013-11-19 15:19:44,097: ERROR/MainProcess] Error in timer: TransactionManagementError("This code isn't under transaction management",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/timer.py", line 166, in apply_entry
entry()
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/timer.py", line 64, in __call__
return self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/timer.py", line 127, in _reschedules
return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/snapshot.py", line 73, in capture
self.state.freeze_while(self.shutter, clear_after=self.clear_after)
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/state.py", line 293, in freeze_while
return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/snapshot.py", line 70, in shutter
self.on_shutter(self.state)
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 129, in on_shutter
transaction.commit()
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 152, in commit
connection.commit()
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 242, in commit
self.set_clean()
  File "/Users/andres/.virtualenvs/rpmwest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 184, in set_clean
raise TransactionManagementError("This code isn't under transaction management")
TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management
[2013-11-19 15:19:45,010: WARNING/MainProcess] Substantial drift from celery@Lyn.local may mean clocks are out of sync.  Current drift is
50400 seconds.  [orig: 2013-11-19 15:19:45.010442 recv: 2013-11-19 01:19:45.009564]
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with Django 1.4.8. Have you figured out a solution yet? My hunch is that this may be due to Django transactions, who are known for not being 100% reliable. It's supposedly much better on Django 1.6, which leads me to think that the latest kombu/celery were only tested for this setup?

Comment: Mmh weird. I'm going to try to upgrade to Django 1.6 and see if it works.

Comment: https://github.com/celery/django-celery/pull/293

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the new guide to django/celery integration?   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html

I converted my project to no longer call djcelery.setup_loader() and instead now have a celery.py under {project}/{project}/celery.py

Also what is your CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND set to?  I have mine set to the djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend

Is it possible that your large clock drift has something to do with it?  Have you tried syncing the clocks?

I'm running django 1.6.1 using celerycam with no issues.